# Using yui to customise select boxes

Tags: javascript, yui

I know how to customize select boxes using such techniqiues as http://ryanfait.com/resources/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/ however Im trying to figure out if yui provides such functionality.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you're looking for something like this: http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/button/#skinning

HTH,
 Ingo